# duplicating mysql records when page refresh?

Tags: php, mysql

i am making a basic review system , its almost done but when i submited a record then when i refresh the page the records are duplicating, how to avoid this ?

[this is my basic review system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQjv5.jpg)

[my MySQL tables looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9s66.jpg)

codes

`//getting data from the database

$data = mysqli_query($connection,"select distinct * from questions");`

```
            <?php

            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
            echo $row['qsttable'].'<br />';
            }               

             ?>
```

**UPDATE**
I got errors again when refreshing the page duplicating the records again ??? anyone else?

Comment: several ways, 1 redirect away after submit, 2 check values on every submit, 3 unique keys in the db

Comment: please post the whole codes

Comment: also, you can use **distinct** statement like this:
select distinct * from questions

Comment: @GrigoryantsArtem I have used your method but still happening the same thing.  I think the redirection is the only way?

Comment: @PrinceJay try this: select distinct qsttable from questions

Comment: problem solved thanks, everyone, i have tried this code
**$data = mysqli_query($connection,"select  distinct * from questions group by qid");**

Comment: you will just end up with a lot of bad data in the db if that is your approach

Answer (score 1):

Suppose form `action="submit.php"` then you are sending `post/get` value to the submit.php page, that retain in submit.php until you redirect or until you manually cleared.
So my suggestion please write redirect code something like

```
header('Location: newpage.php');
```

on form action page(eg:submit.php) and set the status in session and check this session in landing page thus when user refresh never data be duplicated.

Comment: I added your redirect code after  get data query but its automatically redirecting to the newpage.php ?

Comment: try to redirect after insert the review into db

Answer (score -1):

Check the database whether the data is inserting again after refresh. If so then after inserting use unset($_POST) to clear all post data and make condition if(isset($_POST)) before insering in DB

Answer (score -2):

use $data = mysqli_query($connection,"select * from questions group by qid"); may be this will solve your problem if not then please share your whole codes

Comment: thanks for the help I have modified your code by adding  distinct

  ** $data = mysqli_query($connection,"select  distinct * from questions group by qid"); ** and its working

Comment: welcome can you please accept my answer to make it correct.